# asp:FileUpload won't center within a fieldset

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm trying to center a bunch of control within a fieldset and 2 of them are `<asp:FileUpload />` .One is behaving as intended but not the other :

[image]

I've created my fieldset within a `<div id="container">` and inside the fieldset you have a `<div class="content">` which contains the Labels, FileUpload etc.

The aspx file is as follow :

```
<div id="container">
<fieldset>
    <legend style="color:#CC0000; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold">Nouvelle demande de tarif imagé</legend>
        <br />
    <div class="content">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Nom du catalogue : " 
            Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="TB_name" ForeColor="#CC0000" 
            onservervalidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
            Text="Veuillez sélectionner un fichier CSV :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
            <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="csvUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="csvUpload" 
            Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#CC0000" 
            onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" 
            ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
            Text="Veuillez sélectionner un logo (facultatif) :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="pictureUpload" runat="server" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="pictureUpload" 
            ForeColor="#CC0000" onservervalidate="CustomValidator3_ServerValidate" 
            ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Valider" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink_validee" runat="server" Font-Underline="True" 
            ForeColor="#009933" NavigateUrl="~/TarifImageHistorique.aspx">Votre demande a bien été enregistrée</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS :

```
    fieldset
    {
        margin-bottom:20px;
        border:1px solid rgb(149,149,149);
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        width:100%;

    }
    #container
    {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:400px;
    }
    .content
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

I don't get why the second FileUpload won't align as the first one. Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CustomValidator3 in front of second file upload control needs dynamic displaying so just add `Display="Dynamic"` and done.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to put your second file upload control in **`<center>`** tag.
- Below code around line 31

  ```
  ... // your code
  <center>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="pictureUpload" runat="server" />
    </center>
  ... // your code
  ```